# ASP MVC 5 Unable To Format Date Using EditorTemplate Bound To DatePicker

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datepicker, date-format, pikaday

I have the following model and viewmodel, note ExpiryDate is nullable:

```
public class Topic
{
    public DateTime? ExpiryDate { get; set; }

    // Other properties
}

public class TopicViewModel
{
    public DateTime? ExpiryDate { get; set; }

    // Other properties
}
```

In my controller edit method I am setting the date as follows to render in my view. The view uses an editor template to bind a textbox to the pikaday datepicker widget as follows:

```
// Controller method
public ActionResult EditTopic(Guid id)
{
    var topic = _contect.GetTopic(id);

    var viewModel = new TopicViewModel
    {
        ExpiryDate = topic.ExpiryDate

        // Other mappings
    };

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

EditorTemplate- datepicker.cshtml

```
@model Nullable<System.DateTime>
<link rel="stylesheet" href='/content/pikaday/css/pikaday.css' />
<script src='/content/pikaday/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='/content/pikaday/pikaday.js'></script>
<script src="/content/pikaday/plugins/pikaday.jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {
       $('.datepicker').pikaday({
           firstDay: 1,
           format: "DD MMM YYYY"
       });

   });
</script>

@Html.TextBox(string.Empty, ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue, new { @class = "datepicker form-control" })
```

This is my view - EditTopic.cshtml

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ExpiryDate)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ExpiryDate)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ExpiryDate)
</div>
```

Whilst the datepicker get wired and everything works, but the date doesn't display in the format 'DD MMM YYYY' in the textbox once it is returned from the database.

E.g if I have an ExpiryDate stored as 2016-05-17, when it's displayed for editing it is returned as 17 Jan 0000

How do I get the date to format as DD MMM YYYY when it's not null?

Comment: You can edit ExpiryDate property in the model and check if it is null and return the value you want.

Comment: Scripts should never be in an `EditorTemplate` - move them to the main view or layout.

Comment: @ Stephen having the script inside the editor template has no bearing on my issue. Moving it to a layout doesn't resolve my formatting problem?

Comment: I was not claiming it was (but it will be if you were to include 2 datepickers in the same page). Do NOT put scripts in partials or EditorTemplates

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix by adding the following data attribute to my viewmodel:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d MMM yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime? ExpiryDate { get; set; }
```